# Excel VBA, reading values from array from Worksheet.Range

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a project in excel and am having the following problem:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim TestRange As Variant
    TestRange = Worksheets("test_worksheet").Range("Q50:Q60").Value
    
    ' Here an error 9 (Subscript out of range) pops up
    MsgBox (CStr(TestRange(2)))
End Sub
```

As I understand, the `TestRange` variable should contain an array, the array has a size of 11, confirmed by using `UBound(TestRange) - LBound(TestRange) + 1`, but no matter what index I use the error 9 pops up. The return value of `LBound(TestRange)` is 1.

I would like to do this if possible, I have already read some answers and it should be possible to put the range into an array, just don't know how to read from it then.

*note that this is a piece of test code i threw together to confirm the possibility of putting the value of `Worksheet.Range` into an array and then reading it*

Comment: An array extracted from a range is of **2D type**. I mean, it has rows an columns. So, you should try `MsgBox CStr(TestRange(2, 1))`... The respective range has one column.

Comment: This has worked, please post is as an answer so I can close the question. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array extracted from a range is of **2D type**, meaning that it has columns, too. In your case only one. So, you should try:

```
MsgBox CStr(TestRange(2, 1)) 'No need of casting to string, anyhow...
```

If you like 1D arrays more, you can transform `TestRange` in 1D type, by transposing it:

```
MsgBox Application.Transpose(TestRange(2, 1))
```

Or, see all the (transposed) array in Immediate Window `Ctrl + G`:

```
Debug.Print Join(Application.Transpose(TestRange(2, 1)), "|")
```

Answer (score 0):

You currently code will read the vertical range into an array of 2 dimensions.
Add in one more line as below to convert the array into 1 dimension instead

```
Public Sub test()
Dim TestRange As Variant

TestRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Q50:Q60").Value
TestRange = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(TestRange)
' Here an error 9 (Subscript out of range) pops up
MsgBox (CStr(TestRange(2)))
End Sub
```